# "Data conversion error" with BULK INSERT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I am trying to import some data into SQL Server using the Bulk insert command--

This is the error I am getting--

```
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 6 (NClaims).
```

Now, I created a test file with only one row of data which I was able to import successfully--

```
00000005^^18360810^408^30^0
```

However when I added 2 more rows of data (which are very similar to the row above) I got the error message that I have given above. These are the 2 additional rows of data--

```
00000003^^18360801^142^42^0
00000004^^18360000^142^10^0
```

As you can see there does not seem to be any difference (in terms of data length or data types for the 2 rows above compared with the single row given previously)... So why am I getting this error? How do I fix it?

EDIT--

This is the command I am executing--

```
BULK INSERT GooglePatentsIndividualDec2012.dbo.patent
FROM 'C:\Arvind Google Patents Data\patents\1patents_test.csv'
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '^', ROWTERMINATOR='\n');
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact SQL command you are executing? Are you perhaps skipping the header row, which would work for only a single row of data?

Comment: @mellamokb there is no header row in my CSVs-- neither in the file that contains one row of data, nor in the file that contains 3 rows...i have updated my question with the query I have tried to use in SQL Server ...

Comment: Are you sure your rowterminator is `\n` and not `\r`?

Comment: @Hogan yes its \n only...

Comment: @Arvind: I tried it locally with a test file using your sample code, and it worked fine.  You might want to check a hexdump of the file to make sure you don't have strange characters or special encoding of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be patient and make experiments excluding one thing at a time. For example:

1. Remove third row and check if everything ok.
2. If yes, return this row but change `10^0` to `42^0`, check again.
3. Repeat step 2 with all data changing it to values in row 2 which is ok.

You will find the piece of data which causes error.